# What is the loop invariance/invariant that can describe this code's functionality?

Tags: python, loops, loop-invariant

```
def func(no_1,no_2):
    a=no_1
    b=no_2
    while(b):
        a,b=b,a%b
    return a
```

where no_1 and no_2 are positive real numbers

I've figured out that this function returns no_1 and no_2's greates common factor. First, I tried the loop invariance of (no_1%a and no_2%a) ≥ 0 such that a, no_1, and no_2 are positive integers but at termination, i can only prove that no_1%a = 0 = no_2%a, which does not describe the functionality at all. So can anyone tell me what possible loop invariance can this function have that describes its functionality?

Answer (score 0):

In the following I am assuming that both `no_1` and `no_2` are some natural numbers.

I think you could try to introduce an additional symbol `fact` which is non-deterministically assigned to some common factor of `no_1` and `no_2`: assume `no_1 % fact == 0 and no_2 % fact == 0`.

Then as loop invariant you could state that `a >= fact`.

Comment: by introducing do you mean adding to the code? I am not allowed to alter the code unfortunately, I have to explain it as is.

Comment: I do not know what kind of tools you are using to handle loop invariants and prove properties about the code.
In some cases it is possible to introduce symbols used only for the proofs, for example in Dafny these are known as ghost variables.

Comment: Im sorry i dont think im familiar with the stuff you are talking about, and I also think we are not allowed to add symbols for proofing. In any case, I just prove loop invariant by initialization, maintenance, and termination. The most basic one I think. We prove by axioms and such or through the loop invariant if that makes sense.